# Is it possible to have a the magic eraser apply to ALL layers at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gif

I have a gif of characters dancing on a white background, and I want to use the magic eraser (or an equivalent selection tool) to select and clear the white background to make it transparent.

However, the gif is ~150 frames long so doing each layer individually would be tedious, and I'd like to know how to sample all layers any way. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no tool in Photoshop that will let you erase different layers at once.

What you can do instead is **grouping** all your layers and applying a **mask** to the group. I would actually recommend that whenever it's possible (and by that I mean almost always!), you use masks instead of the eraser.

It works with animated gifs too:

[image]

Comment: Will it still work for animation if they're in a group?

Comment: @Joshpho Yes, it will. I just checked it :) Mine has 'Propagate Frame 1' ticked, but it's also disabled so I don't know if it's necessary.